# Separate Learndash / post categories

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to put a Learndash site up for someone. It turns out that Learndash doesn't have its own categories for courses, but uses Wordpress post's categories...

That seems rather short sighted (at least to me). In this case they have a blog as well as courses and it would be fantastic to have separate course categories.

Is it possible to get Learndash to use its own categories (custom taxonomies) which are distinct from the blog post categories? I've tried googling and checked the Learndash site for add-ons, etc but so far I don't have a solution. I'm considering perhaps using Advanced Custom Fields to hack it but that might not be intuitive for the administrators.

Comment: you just want to create a custom taxonomy under Learndash post type?

Comment: Hi @DevKiran, yes that's pretty much it... based on your comment (which made me think that it should be easy) I added a taxonomy for it using CPT UI. That's worked in the sense that the taxonomy now appears in the course edit screen.  Now I need to find out how (if) I can override the tab'ed link at the top to use my custom taxonomy..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured this out!

I used CPT UI plugin to add a taxonomy to the "Courses" post type. That showed my custom categories in the right side bar of the Courses editor, along with the Categories from the built in post types. To remove the built in post categories I disabled their display from screen options...

Then, the tabs above the editor in the Course editor screen has a tab linking to the categories, but as you might have guessed, that links to the built in type categories.

To get around that I checked the Learndash source and saw that they apply_filters to the array which those tabs are built from so I was able to add_filter() to my functions file to change that tab's link!

Now I have my own custom categories for the courses which are separate form the built in post types categories!

The code I used in my functions is:

```
function ifx_course_category( $Tabs ) 
{

    $ReturnArray = array();

    foreach($Tabs as $key => $Tab)
    {

        if($Tab["id"] == "edit-category")
        {
            $Tab["link"] = str_replace("taxonomy=category", "taxonomy=ifx_course_category", $Tab["link"]);  
        }

        $ReturnArray[$key] = $Tab;
    }

    return $ReturnArray;
}
add_filter('learndash_admin_tabs', 'ifx_course_category');
```

I put up a post about it on my blog (mostly so I can remember what I did if I need it again). For reference its here: [Separate Categories for learndash](http://softsmart.co.za/2017/02/14/creating-separate-categories-learndash/)